# which function in mapbox-gl.js draws the path returning from osrm?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Which function in mapbox-gl.js draws the path returning from osrm?
I tried with event listener click option in chrome to see which function is doing the drawing part and unfortunately I couldn't find the line.

Comment: Can you give more context as to what you're asking? OSRM is not part of Mapbox-GL-JS. What application are you using that combines these two libraries?

Comment: Sorry Yes They are not using OSRM but they are completely similar, I changed mapboxgl-direction.js and now I am using OSRM,
By the way, I put an input box (for source and destination coordinates) with a button on the page that calls OSRM, then I am going to use mapboxgl to draw the path

Answer (score 0):

If you have already got the path data, you can create an empty GeoJSON as the map source and keep updating the GeoJSON with the path data. You can find more details in this example: [Aminate a line](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-a-line/)